# Gradle Build repositories precedence

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

we have trasnstioned to Gradle recently in our projects and we are aware that maven repository URLs to fetch the required artiifacts can be declared both in settings.gradle(under pluginManagement) and build.gradle as well.

**I would like to know three things here:**

1) "repositories{...}" declaration under Which one is mandatory?

2) If we have repositories declared in both the places which one is picked and takes precedence during the gradle builds?

3) why we have two places two declare repositories?

Any help on clearing these doubts is appreciated. I'm new to gradle, so please excuse if this very basic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Repositories in the Gradle build script (`build.gradle`/`build.gradle.kts`) are mandatory.
2. Repositories defined in the Gradle build script and Gradle settings file do not affect each other. Build script repositories are for your application while settings repositories are for Gradle plugins.
3. As mentioned in (2), one is for application dependencies and one is for Gradle plugins.

This documented in the following: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:plugin-vs-build-repos